# Using Conversion Studio by To-Increase to import Notes into Microsoft Dynamics AX 2009

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2009, axapta

Currently, I'm using Conversion Studio to bring in a CSV file and store the contents in an AX table.  This part is working.  I have a block defined and the fields are correctly mapped.

The CSV file contains several comments columns, such as Comments-1, Comments-2, etc.  There are a fixed number of these.  The public comments are labeled as Comments-1...5, and the private comments are labeled as Private-Comment-1...5.

The desired result would be to bring the data into the AX table (as is currently working) and either concatenate the comment fields or store them as separate comments into the DocuRef table as internal or external notes.

Would it not require just setting up a new block in the Conversion Studio project that I already have setup?  Can you point me to a resource that maybe shows a similar procedure or how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After chasing the rabbit down the deepest of rabbit holes, I discovered that the **easiest** way to do this is like so:

Override the onEntityCommit method of your Document Handler (that extends AppDataDocumentHandler), like so:

```
AppEntityAction onEntityCommit(AppDocumentBlock documentBlock, AppBlock fromBlock, AppEntity toEntity)
{

  AppEntityAction ret;
  int64 recId; // Should point to the record currently being imported into CMCTRS
  ;
  ret = super(documentBlock, fromBlock, toEntity);
  recId = toEntity.getRecord().recId;
  // Do whatever you need to do with the recId now
  return ret;

}
```

Here is my method to insert the notes, in case you need that too:

```
private static boolean insertNote(RefTableId _tableId, int64 _docuRefId, str _note, str _name, boolean _isPublic)
{
  DocuRef docuRef;
  boolean insertResult = false;
  ;
  if (_docuRefId)
  {
    try
    {
        docuRef.clear();
        ttsbegin;
        docuRef.RefCompanyId = curext();
        docuRef.RefTableId = _tableId;
        docuRef.RefRecId = _docuRefId;
        docuRef.TypeId = 'Note';
        docuRef.Name = _name;
        docuRef.Notes = _note;
        docuRef.Restriction = (_isPublic) ? DocuRestriction::External : DocuRestriction::Internal;
        docuRef.insert();
        ttscommit;

        insertResult = true;
    }
    catch
    {
        ttsabort;
        error("Could not insert " + ((_isPublic) ? "public" : "private") + " comment:\n\n\t\"" + _note + "\"");
    }
  }
  return insertResult;
}
```